# Регулярное выражение не возвращает вхождений, хотя на Regex101 работает

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
Regex regProgram = new Regex(@"(""|«)\W{1,}(""|»)");
matches = regProgram.Matches(asProfDev[nDevIter]);
```

Значение asProfDev[nDevIter]: «Применение профессиональных стандартов в образовательной организации. Требования к кадрам и к разработке программ», 36 час., удостоверение №782406568325, 2018 г. СПбГЭТУ "ЛЭТИ"

На Regex101 всё работает: https://regex101.com/r/2a2WLD/1 , а в программе в matches ничего не возвращается. Как можно это исправить?

Экранировать пробовал, вот что выходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @rdorn так в исходной строке экранирование правильное, зачем `@` убирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что \W означает любой символ, не являющийся частью слова.

Javascript считает, что слова бывают только английские - потому в браузере всё и "работает".

.NET знает, что русские буквы в словах тоже встречаются - потому они и не могут найтись как \W